# Custom bean validation invalidValue is always the entire object

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

```
Spring Boot 2.7.18
```

When implementing a custom ConstraintValidator, specifying the node(s) to a nested property does not affect getInvalidValue() when processing the ConstraintViolation objects that result.

Using built-in property-level constraints like @NotNull works correctly.

Is this possible with a class-level constraint?

**Validated class:**

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@EventConstraint
public class Event {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String productId;
    @Positive
    private Long positiveNumber;
}
```

**Constraint:**

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = EventValidator.class)
@Target({TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface EventConstraint {
    String message() default "Event is invalid";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

**Validating method:**

```
public Event saveEvent(Event event) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Event>> violations = validator.validate(event);
    if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
        throw new ConstraintViolationException("Invalid event", violations);
    }
    return eventRepository.save(event);
}
```

**isValid Implementation:**

```
public boolean isValid(@NotNull Event event, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
    context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("Invalid event")
            .addPropertyNode("productId")
            .addConstraintViolation();
    return false;
}
```

**Result when using @Positive**

```
{
    "message": "must be greater than 0",
    "field": "positiveNumber",
    "invalidValue": -1
}
```

**Result when using custom constraint**

```
{
    "message": "Invalid event",
    "field": "productId",
    "invalidValue": {
        "id": null,
        "productId": "someValue",
        "positiveNumber": -1
    }
}
```

**Expected result**

```
{
    "message": "Invalid event",
    "field": "productId",
    "invalidValue": "someValue"
}
```

Comment: No as it is class level and with that the invalid value is the class instance itself.

Comment: Then what's the point of being able to specify property nodes?

Comment: That is for specifying the field/fields not the invalid value. It is for providing a bit more context.

Comment: Is there no built-in way of resolving the nested invalid value? It seems like something that lots of consumers would want to know.

Comment: Then don't write a class level validation.

Comment: That's not possible, the properties have to be validated against one another. I'm just trying to avoid having to write my own property resolver